# Correct way to incorporate a docstring in a def* macro?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, defmacro

I am working my way through Practical Common Lisp. I got to the example where you define a `deftest` macro that works like `defun` with some added functionality. This got me thinking that it would be nice to be able to add a docstring. I have found that both of the following work, but is one of them more correct? Is there a "right" way to achieve the optional-docstring-like behaviour of `defun`?

```lisp
(defmacro deftest (name parameters &body body)
  (let ((docstring ""))
    (when (stringp (car body)) (setf docstring (car body) body (cdr body)))
    `(defun ,name ,parameters
       ,docstring
       (let ((*test-name* (append *test-name* (list ',name))))
         ,@body))))

(defmacro deftest (name parameters &optional docstring &body body)
  (when (not (stringp docstring)) (setf docstring ""))
  `(defun ,name ,parameters
     ,docstring
     (let ((*test-name* (append *test-name* (list ',name))))
       ,@body)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you probably want to parse out both a possible docstring and any declarations from the body of the function, so you can put the declarations where they belong.  I use something like this:

```
(defun parse-body (body)
    (multiple-value-bind (docstring decls/forms)
        (if (stringp (first body))
            (values (first body) (rest body))
          (values nil body))
      (loop for remainder on decls/forms
            while (and (not (null remainder))
                       (consp (first remainder))
                       (eql (car (first remainder)) 'declare))
            collect (first remainder) into decls
            finally (return (values docstring decls remainder)))))
```

And then your `deftest` would be

```
(defmacro deftest (name parameters &body body)
  (multiple-value-bind (docstring decls forms) (parse-body body)
    `(defun ,name ,parameters
       ,@(if docstring (list docstring) '())
       ,@decls
       (let ((*test-name* (append *test-name* (list ',name))))
         ,@forms))))
```

I wish I could say that I have a standard `parse-body` function, but I don't: I just write a new one each time.

Comment: Thank you, this is a clear answer. There's just one piece that I'm still confused about. Why is it necessary/preferable to use `,@(list docstring)` instead of `,docstring` alone?

Comment: @bashfuloctopus See also https://common-lisp.net/project/parse-declarations/manual/html_node/parse_002dbody.html

Comment: @bashfuloctopus: sorry that was a botch: I had a working version then thought 'oh no, I can be clever and avoid the conditional' (which I can't) resulting in a broken version which I never tested.  The trick it now does right is to use `,@` to splice in an *empty* list (ie nothing, since it is splicing) if there is no docstring, otherwise to splice in a single-element list of the docstring, which means putting the docstring in.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @tfb crafty! I was hackily giving the function an empty docstring rather than splicing the empty list.

Comment: @coredump `parse-body` looks handy, but I'm not sure how to get access to it. I don't see a download link, and I wasn't able to load it using `(asdf:load-system 'parse-declarations)`. What am I missing?

Comment: @coredump I was able to load the package finally after seeing this article https://40ants.com/lisp-project-of-the-day/2020/05/0067-parse-declarations.html How we're supposed to know that the package is really called parse-declarations-1.0 is beyond me!